# cannot cast and object from a lst which contains a base class

Tags: java

I have an empty abstract base class

```
abstract class Base{
    Base(){}
}
```

Then I have several classes that extend this base class

```
class A extends Base{

}
```

Then I intantiate these classes and put into list.

```
 A it = new A();
 ArrayList<Base> list = new ArrayList<Base>();
 list.add(it);  // add A object
```

then I want to do something like

```
   for(Base msg : List){
       if( msg instanceof A){
             A obj = (A)msg; 
        }

    }
But I'm getting errors.
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: If you're iterating over a list and checking `instanceof`, you're using the list wrong. The whole idea behind inheritance is that you can treat an `A` object like a `Base` object and not care that it's actually an `A`.

Comment: What specifically are you doing, and what specific error do you get ?

Comment: "But I'm getting errors" is *never* enough information. What errors? Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't check it for being A. Consider this

```
abstract class Base{
    Base(){}
    void doSomething() { System.out.println("AwesomePossum"); }
}

class A extends Base {
    @Override void doSomething() { System.out.println("Frankie O'Malley"); }
}
```

Then later, when you're iterating, instead of doing something like

```
for(Base msg : list) {
    if(msg instanceof A) // BAD
}
```

do this:

```
for(Base msg : List) {
    msg.doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would normally expect `Base` to declare the methods provided by `A`, and consequently you could pull a `Base` reference out and use it, *regardless* of the fact that the implementation is `A`.

If the types in your list don't adhere to a common interface contract, I would question why you're putting them in a list together. It will make life very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(Base msg : List){<---List is used variable name is list
```

You are not using variable `list` to iterate instead you are using `List`.That is why you are getting errors.

It should be

```
for(Base msg : list)
```